# Laptop has started losing RDP connection when lid is closed and reopened

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, remote-desktop, connection

I am trying to assist a user who is carrying a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 11e (Windows 10).

This user is a physician who is constantly seeing patients in various exam rooms and needs to maintain an open RDP session to his EMR system throughout the day.

He has been using this laptop since March 2015 with no problems.  However, in the last week it seems every time he closes the lid, his RDP session gets disconnected, requiring him to reconnect manually.

We have not changed our Wifi network settings, nor have we updated the Wifi drivers on this laptop.

Windows 10 installed a feature rollup on 1 December, but otherwise no updates have been installed lately.  I have checked to ensure the Power Settings are correct (Close Lid is set to "do nothing"), and have created a new power profile. I also checked in Device Manager to ensure the Wifi card is not allowed to be turned off to save power.

Another user has the exact same model laptop in this office and is not experiencing this issue.

I updated the Wifi card drivers to the latest available version, but the problem still occurs.

Any suggestions to remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can start by taking a network dump and see exactly what is happening (maybe the network card is disconnecting).

Comment: @cdavid so run Wireshark on the laptop itself? then look for what?

Comment: Check the SYSTEM log for power transitions. This is the best place to look to see if something is going in to low power mode or standby. You'll also find network connects and disconnects there. How do you know nothing changed on the RDP server? Maybe it is timing out there. Check the logs on the server.

Comment: SInce you said you have another user with the same laptop, try swapping hard drives.  This will let you know if it is a hardware or software issue.

Comment: @Appleoddity The RDP connection is provided by our EMR software provider.  I don't have access to the server, unfortunately.

Comment: System logs as suggested by @Appleoddity are also a good idea. My guess is that something happens when the user closes the lid (be it either a network disconnect or a network change of sorts) that triggers an RDP disconnect. Try looking at the specific times between the user closing the lid and the RDP connection disconnects (you can filter for port 3389).

Comment: One other thought I had was - does the "user closes lid" event trigger any sort of resize of the RDP window? I know previous versions of the RDP protocol would do a reconnect when the RDP window is resized (e.g.: due to a monitor being unplugged).